# I have quarters and nickels, but not any dough

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I have quarters and nickels, but not any dough,
Hundreds of feet all stretched in a row,
Two dozen leave two, with zebras on grass,
My minutes tick by but just an hour will pass.
You might be able to solve this when pigs fly
All that’s left is- **what am I**?

Comment: Ideas so far (ROT13): nycunorg, onggrel, and some more which I discarded even quicker. None of them quite seems to fit everything though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are a

> football (American) game.

I have quarters and nickels, but not any dough,

> Quarterback and nickel backs are positions.

Hundreds of feet all stretched in a row,

> The field is 300 feet long.

Two dozen leave two, with zebras on grass,

> 24 - 2 = 22 players on the field. Referees are often called zebras due to their striped uniforms.

My minutes tick by but just an hour will pass.

> The game is 60 minutes long (on the game clock).

You might be able to solve this when pigs fly

> The ball is called the 'pigskin'.

Comment: exactly! great answer :)

Comment: Also, of course, the (you know what) is divided into four (you know what)s.